# .txt file with \t and \n separators to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, txt

How can I read the attached txt file as a pandas dataframe?

my txt file

```
'CHROM\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tQUAL\tFILTER\tINFO\tFORMAT\tW2008872\n', 'chr1\t36932417\t.\tC\tT\t48.00\tSB\tDP=1618;TI=NM_172313,NM_156039,NM_000760;GI=CSF3R,CSF3R,CSF3R;FC=Synonymous_Q684Q,Synonymous_Q711Q,Synonymous_Q684Q;EXON\tGT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX\t0/1:48:1582,36:0.0222:20:-0.0009:48\n', 'chr1\t36933198\t.\tG\tT\t100.00\tPASS\tDP=513;TI=NM_172313,NM_156039,NM_000760;GI=CSF3R,CSF3R,CSF3R;FC=Missense_T640N,Missense_T640N,Missense_T640N;EXON\tGT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX\t0/1:100:410,103:0.2008:20:-100.0000:100\n', 'chr1\t36933569\t.\tA\tG\t100.00\tSB\tDP=1154;TI=NM_172313,NM_156039,NM_000760;GI=CSF3R,CSF3R,CSF3R;FC=Silent,Silent,Silent\tGT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX\t0/1:100:1093,59:0.0511:20:-0.0236:100\n', 'chr1\t36933574\t.\tT\tG\t100.00\tSB\tDP=1236;TI=NM_172313,NM_156039,NM_000760;GI=CSF3R,CSF3R,CSF3R;FC=Silent,Silent,Silent\tGT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX\t0/1:100:1114,116:0.0939:20:-0.0001:100\n', ...
```

Disable outcome:

```
CHROM POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO FORMAT W2008872 # (Header)
chr1 36932417 . C T 48.00 SB DP=1618;TI=NM_172313,NM_156039,NM_000760;GI=CSF3R,CSF3R,CSF3R;FC=Synonymous_Q684Q,Synonymous_Q711Q,Synonymous_Q684Q;EXON GT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX 0/1:48:1582,36:0.0222:20:-0.0009:48 
chr1 ...
```

I have tried sustituying \t to coma but there is coma and semi coma in the values as you can see.

Comment: What is the schema of the expected output?

Comment: Does it really `\t` tabulation or 2 characters "\" and "t"? Same question for `\n`